# What method and tool for regression analysis for a multimodal distribution in R?

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression, multimodal

I have a set of variables X1 and X2 and Y with relationship plot as shown below. X2 values are used for color coding.

X1, X2, and X3 are integer variables.

[image]

The observed pattern is multimodal.

What is the best way to predict Y based on X1 and X2?

Can we use non-linear or hurdle models for this?

Also what are the tools available to achieve this in R?

Comment: This will get closed as its off topic for SO -- coding questions only here :) But maybe try a spline or other GAM (generalized additive model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no need to worry about the distribution of the response. Although you are showing a bivariate plot, it is possible that the multi-modality is explained by `X2` (or other, missing variables)

It is the distribution of the model residuals that matters (if it matters at all).

If the residuals are non-normal, then certain inferences may be invalid, although this may not be a problem at all if the model is used for prediction.

If you really do have a curvilinear association then you could consider:

- transformations
- non-linear terms
- splines
- generalised additive models (GAMs)
- non-linear models

Of course, if the underlying problem is that you have missing explanatory variables, then some of these approaches may lead to an overfitted model.